# How to make random Beta in python like normal between two value ?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to make random beta in python like normal between two extreme values (ex : 800 / 1000 ). I use this code with numpy random.beta. My problem, I don't have min and max value with normalize and I want keep shape of value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import numpy as np
import math
from random import gauss
#####################################
# Parameters definition
n=100.
#deviation de 20 %
n_min = n - n*0.2
n_max = n + n*0.2
var_n_min = 100000.
var_n_max = 0.
m=100000
for i in range (0,m):
    alea_var_n.append(np.random.beta(50,70))
    alea_var_tau.append(np.random.beta(50,70))
    if var_n_min > alea_var_n[i] :
       var_n_min = alea_var_n[i]
    if var_n_max < alea_var_n[i] :
       var_n_max = alea_var_n[i]

for i in range (0,m):
# Normalize 
    alea_var_n[i] = n_min +  alea_var_n[i] * (n_max- n_min)/(var_n_max + var_n_min)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`numpy`'s `random.beta`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.beta.html) will give a value between zero and one, so to apply the same distribution between `x` and `y` you simply do:

```
z = x + (np.random.beta(a, b) * (y - x))
```

Comment: Doesn't this need to be `(y-x)` instead of just `y`?